# What are ifconfig.me/forwarded IP addreses?

Tags: proxy, ip, ifconfig

When I use the ifconfig.me service, by running the following command:

$> curl ifconfig.me/forwarded

I returns a list of IP addresses.  does anyone know what this IP addresses are.  I am behind a proxy, so I assume it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the service looks at the X-Forwarded-For field in the http request.  This is (optionally) added by proxy servers in the path, referencing the IP address of the device they are requesting on behalf of.